# Endpoint .api file not updated automatically

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-plugin-eclipse

I am using Java + GPE + Cloud end points.

It used to be the case that my end point api file would automatically update whenever I change the relevant java source code. For some reason this has now stopped working.

I created a very simple dummy endpoint project and the api file is automatically generated here. But not in my real project.

Now to see my changes in api file - I have to click on "Generate Cloud End Point Client Library". This is slow, freezes up eclipse and lowers my productivity.

Any suggestions/ideas ?

Regards,

Sathya

Answer (score 1):

Check your output directory for your classes. If that's changed, it won't properly update the .api file any. I found this out after adding Maven to my Eclipse project, and adding Maven changed my output directory.